# Intuition for orientation of a simplex (in 3 dimensions)

Tags: soft-question, intuition, simplex, orientation

In trying to begin to learn basic homological algebra, i am confronted with orientation of simplices. The definition seems unmotivated and unintuitive: for $n$-simplices with $n \in \{-1,0,1,2\}$, it is intuitive to visualize: intuitively, given a 2-simplex, we can walk to the left or to the right. For $n=3$ and above, the definition seems arbitrary. Is there a "geometric intuition" for this?

Definition of *orientation*: two (ordered) simplices with same vertices have same orientation if one is the componentwise image of an even permutation of the other. Else they are said to have opposite orientation.

Comment: Could you please add to the question your definition of _orientation_? (This will presumably entail including the definition of a _simplex_ as well.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang added

Comment: Here's an attempt at geometric intuition: Assuming the standard $n$-simplex is the convex hull of the standard basis vectors in $\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$, swapping one pair of vertices corresponds to a reflection, which "reverses orientation," while swapping two pairs of vertices corresponds to a rotation. Since a composition of rotations is a rotation, and the composition of a rotation and a reflection is a reflection, a vertex permutation preserves orientation iff the permutation is even. <> All this presumes a certain underlying belief that permutations have an invariant parity....

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang This makes me realize i don't have intuition for orientation in $\mathbb R^n$ for $n>1$. Maybe i should ask another question about that. It still seems like a strange thing to do, to associate an orientation to simplices, but for $n=1$ it makes sense to me because of analogy with closed paths.

Comment: Possibly of interest: [geometric meaning of orientation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551768/geometrical-meaning-of-orientation-on-vector-space) and [higher-dimensional analogues of handedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884953/what-are-the-higher-dimensional-analogues-of-left-and-right-handedness)